# How to add ssl certificate to websocket to convert the url from ws to wss?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, websocket, webrtc

I am trying to make a video call web application using 
**webrtc** and in that i use websocket server in node.js for signaling purpose.

The webrtc application works well in **localhost** with **ws://** websocket url but when i hosted the webrtc application into my server (windows server 2012, IIS ) it required **https://** for browser to give access to the camera .

So i added ssl to my website and it is **https://**.

And i also converted my **ws://** url to **wss://** url by adding my **https://** ssl certificate to websocket server but after that i get the below error when i try to access the websocket url from chrome browser

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

This is what i am currently doing in websocket server.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = new https.createServer({
     cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
     key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem')
});

server.listen(8080);

console.log(server.cert);

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

var users = {};

wss.on('connection', function (connection) {

   console.log("User connected");
});
```

And i access it in my client side javascript like this.

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://server ip address :8080');

conn.onopen = function () {
  console.log("Connected to the signaling server");
};
```

So what part am i doing wrong?

So can i use the same ssl that i bought for my website or should i need to buy new ssl.

And is this the right way to make the websocket url from **ws://** to **wss://** in node.js

Thanks

Comment: https is working? openssl s_client -connect serverip:port returns what?

Comment: the ssl certificate is issued for a given domain name, so in order for certificates to work properly the certificate used in the node server must belong to the domain name on which you are deploying your application . If you are deploying your application on a different domain name then you need to buy a new certificate for that domain.